# What is the right way to redefine macros defined by babel?

Tags: macros, babel, naming, patching

If I want to use the `babel` package and redefine a macro such as `\contentsname`, what is the right way to go about this? Just putting `\renewcommand` in the preamble doesn't work.

This sort of works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\AtBeginDocument{%
        \renewcommand\contentsname{Foo}%
}
\begin{document}
% \selectlanguage{english}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

but if you uncomment the `\selectlanguage{english}`, the definition is undone.

The best I could come up with is to use the following.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\captionsenglish{Contents}{Foo}{}{}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multilingual class/style file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/multilingual-class-style-file)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `\addto\captionsenglish`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand\contentsname{Foo}%
}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}% For testing purposes
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

EDIT: See e.g p. 78 of the babel documentation, where the definitions are changed for the Esperanto language (`\addto\captionsesperanto`).

Answer (score 4):

`Babel` provides hooks for this sort of redefinitions as follows, if for example you wish to hook onto the greek option you add captions such as:

```
\addto\captionsgreek{
  \def\contentsname{prologos}
}
```

You need to do the same for english

```
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \def\contentsname{Foo}
  ...
  }
```

Also see [Multilingual class/style file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/multilingual-class-style-file)

Comment: Yikes. My question is an exact duplicate. This should be closed.